# parsing my array is not working with map method

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to access my array's "value".
It returns undefined.
What is wrong??

```
 res:   ["[{\"value\":\"121.0|81.0\",\"endDate\":\"Feb 21 2021 07:50:00\",\"startDate\":\"Feb 21 2021 07:50:00\",\"type\":\"bloodpressure\"}]"]
```

```
let res = JSON.parse(result)
      console.log(res)
      const values = res.map(result => {
        const { value, startDate } = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log("value", value)                         //always return undefined
        let final = value + "     -      " + startDate
        return final;
       });
```

Comment: your element in array is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `JSON.parse(result);` returns an array, considering the argument it receives. You must access the array element you want to get the data.

One example of how you could do that:

```js
const [first, ...rest] = JSON.parse(result); // or accessing [0] position
const { value, startDate } = first;
```

Answer (score 0):

in line 4 you don't need to parse the result as an object, it's an object there because in the first line you parse it, all you have to do is turn it into:

```
 const { value, startDate } = result;
```